# I’m trying to get python to save as a user defined file name in a specific folder

Tags: python, excel

I can get python to open an excel file and then save that same excel file, but that’s causing issues when I merge cells and then try to run the program again. I could resolve this issue if I can open the same excel template via python every time and then when the program is finished, it will save that excel file as a user defined name within the same folder the template was opened from. I know there is a saveAs function but I can’t find enough information to be able to get it to work. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] of your code. Please also include the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: My reccomendation for reading and copy/paste of code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-automate-an-excel-sheet-in-python/ .

Comment: What are you using to read/write Excel files? If you're on openpyxl then the `wb.save()` method accepts a file name